Does including a header obviate the need for extern declarations?
On page 33 of K&R (The C Programming Language, 2e), they remark that

If the program is in several source files, and a variable is defined in file1 and used in file2 and
file3, then extern declarations are needed in file2 and file3 to connect the occurrences of the
variable. The usual practice is to collect extern declarations of variables and functions in a
separate file, historically called a header, that is included by #include at the front of each
source file. The suffix .h is conventional for header names. The functions of the standard
library, for example, are declared in headers like <stdio.h>.

I am trying to understand how the first and second sentences above are connected. In particular, is the suggestion that the "usual practice" mentioned in the second sentence is a way to circumvent the requirement of using extern declarations noted in the first sentence?
Let me rephrase and expand. Does the first sentence essentially say that if I don't use a #include (as in the second sentence) then one needs to use extern declarations in order to let a linker (?) know that it needs to look for said variable in another object file? In contrast, perhaps this is not necessary if I do use a #include declaration of a header which defines this variable because then this is text substitution (by the preprocessor) and so the variable is declared in the same object file as that in which it's used?
I suspect in the end that my confusion arises from not fully understanding the compilation (and linking process).

What the preprocessor basically does with a #include directive, is to insert the entire contents of the included file into the source file, making it a single unit (a translation unit). If the header file contains an extern declaration of the variable you need, then it's like the source file contains it, and you don't need another declaration.

You need to understand the difference between a source file, a header, and a translation unit (TU).  The TU is the source file, plus any headers that it includes (directly or indirectly) — and that's what the compiler really compiles. If you include extern declarations in a header and include that header in the source file (directly or indirectly), then the extern declarations are visible in the TU just as surely as if you'd placed the declarations in the source file. The reason to declare them in a header is the reduced risk of inconsistency — of different declarations in different files.

I am still not sure I understand then @JonathanLeffler . Say I have a global variable var which I use in my main(). My understanding is that I would not need to use an extern var; declaration in main() iff I either declare var in that same source file or if I use #include as you describe, but that I would need to use extern var; if var were declared in another object file which was not #included in my present file (i.e. if they were only connected by the linker). That's more of what my question is about if that makes sense?

@n.m.couldbeanAI — but some global variables are more or less necessary — think stdin, stdout, stderr.  Yes, you probably could add functions that assume stderr for the output stream (there are already functions that assume stdin for the input stream and stdout for the output stream) but it would make the API more bulky, and hence harder to learn.

@JonathanLeffler Yes but they come with stdio.h, no need to think where to declare them and how. They could be compiler built-ins for all we know.

Copying and expanding on a comment:

You need to understand the difference between a source file, a header, and a translation unit (TU). The TU is the source file, plus any headers that it includes (directly or indirectly) — and that's what the compiler really compiles. If you include extern declarations in a header and include that header in the source file (directly or indirectly), then the extern declarations are visible in the TU just as surely as if you'd placed the declarations in the source file. The reason to declare them in a header is the reduced risk of inconsistency — of different declarations in different files.

But this was followed up with:

I am still not sure I understand then. Say I have a global [integer] variable var which I use in my main(). My understanding is that I would not need to use an extern int var; declaration in main() iff I either declare var in that same source file or if I use #include as you describe, but that I would need to use extern int var; if var were declared in another object file which was not #included in my present file (i.e. if they were only connected by the linker). That's more of what my question is about, if that makes sense?

You need to read How do I use extern to share variables between source files?, which in turn references What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?
I've quietly assumed that var has the type int — it doesn't much matter what the type is, but it needs a type.
Somewhere in amongst the collection of object files that you link to create your program, there must be one (and only one) file scope definition of the variable var with external linkage (which is not the same as being preceded by extern).
This might be written:
int var;       // Roughly equivalent to int var = 0;

or
int var = 37;  // Or any other relevant value

Formally, the first variation is a tentative definition; it ceases to be tentative if there isn't an alternative, non-tentative definition by the end of the TU.
The header will contain:
extern int var;    // No initializer


Key Point
All files that use var, and the file that defines var, will include the only header that declares the variable.

This gives the vital cross-checking necessary to ensure that everything is consistent.  It will require some care to organize the contents of headers so that small source files are not inundated with copious unused declarations (and type definitions, etc).  But with practice, it becomes easy.  You should also ensure that your headers are self-contained, idempotent and minimal.
IMO, you should never write a declaration of any function with external linkage in any source file.  If the function is to be used from multiple source files, there should be a header to declare the function, which should be included both where the function is defined and where it is used.  If the function is not to be used from multiple source files, it should be defined (and perhaps declared) as static.  If a static function is defined before it is used, there is no need to declare it separately, though some projects may prefer to declare all static functions near the top of the source file, even though it is not strictly necessary.  If a static function is called before it is defined, you must declare it before using (in C99 or later — though compilers, especially older compilers, are hit'n'miss about enforcing that without help from the warning options).

Going to accept this but I still have a lot to learn and do have one follow-up question if possible. From your Key Point: Why is it necessary to include the header (which has the extern declaration) in the file which defines var? Is this so that the variable is “exportable” to other translation units/files? I would have thought that that the file which defines var uniquely does not need to make an extern declaration (which is to say, does not need to include the header which makes that extern declaration).

At one level, you're right — the defining file doesn't need the header.  However, include it anyway — it completes the cross-checking.  If your source file defines double var = 3.14; but the header declares int var; and is used by all the files that reference var except the one that defines it, then you are in a nightmare scenario.  If you include the header in the file that defines the variable, the compiler will complain about the mismatched types, heading off a lot of pain.  Headers are the glue that holds your code together, ensuring consistency.

That's also why external functions should be declared in a header and that header should be included both where the function is defined and where it is used.  If you don't follow the rule, you will have to write the function declarations in multiple source files, which is fine until you have to change the function interface.  At that point, you (a) have to edit all the files to bring them back in line, and (b) the compiler can't tell you that you screwed up.  If the declarations are in a header, then incompatible changes will be flagged as compilation errors.

That makes sense. Thank you again for the help!

Including a header with declarations is a way of putting those declarations into a source file. It does not obviate the need for external declarations; it fills the need for external declarations. The declarations are effectively in the source file whether they are typed there manually or are included via header.

… in order to let a linker (?) know that it needs to look for said variable in another object file?…

A declaration provides information to the compiler, not to the linker.
The linker always looks for definitions in the files it is given. Whenever it sees a use of a name in any object module, it looks for a definition of that name in some object module (possibly the same one, possibly an earlier object module in its process, possibly a later one).
A declaration tells the compiler what type of entity the name refers to—whether it is a function or an object or a type name or something else, and what type of function or object it is, and so on. Some declarations are also definitions, in that they tell the compiler to make the thing the name refers to. Some declarations are not definitions and just tell the compiler about the characteristics of the thing, but the actual definition is to be found elsewhere.
